# Fetching permissions of a GCP Service account

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm working on a project where I need to programmatically retrieve the permissions assigned to a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Service Account using Java and the GCP maven dependency. I've been exploring the GCP Java documentation but couldn't find a straightforward way to achieve this.

Could someone please guide me on how to fetch the permissions associated with a GCP Service Account using Java? Are there specific API calls or methods available in the GCP Java SDK that facilitate this task?

I would appreciate any code snippets, examples, or references that could help me understand and implement this functionality effectively.

Answer (score 4):

What you ask is "complex". If fact, you can create a policy binding at different level: Organization, folder, project and resources.

You can also grant your service account on another projects, on another organizations,...

So it's impossible to see all the bindings, especially when you don't have the permission to see them (external projects, folders or org if you are not allowed on them,....)

On the scope where you have policy binding view permissions, I recommend to use [Policy Analyzer](https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/analyze-iam-policies#policy-analyzer-principal-resource-access-rest).

However, here again, it's not so simple: there isn't API to use it, you have to use REST api calls.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this java script maybe it work for your use case.

```
import com.google.api.services.iam.v1.Iam;
import com.google.api.services.iam.v1.model.Binding;
import com.google.api.services.iam.v1.model.GetIamPolicyResponse;
import com.google.api.services.iam.v1.model.Policy;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class GcpPermissionFetcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String projectId = "your-project-id";
        String serviceAccountEmail = "your-service-account@your-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

        // Create IAM client
        Iam iam = IAMServiceAccountExample.createIAMClient();

        // Fetch the IAM policy for the resource (project in this case)
        Policy policy = iam.projects().getIamPolicy(projectId, new GetIamPolicyResponse()).execute();

        // Find bindings for the service account
        List<Binding> bindings = policy.getBindings();
        for (Binding binding : bindings) {
            if (serviceAccountEmail.equals(binding.getRole())) {
                System.out.println("Role: " + binding.getRole());
                System.out.println("Members: " + binding.getMembers());
                // Add more logic as needed
            }
        }
    }
}
```